# Compact storage coefficients of a multivariate polynomial

Tags: arrays, algorithm, math

### The setup

I am writing a code for dealing with polynomials of degree `n` over `d`-dimensional variable `x` and ran into a problem that others have likely faced in the past. Such polynomial can be characterized by coefficients `c(alpha)` corresponding to `x^alpha`, where `alpha` is a length `d` multi-index specifying the powers the `d` variables must be raised to.

The dimension and order are completely general, but known at compile time, and could be easily as high as `n = 30` and `d = 10`, though probably not at the same time. The coefficients are dense, in the sense that most coefficients are non-zero.

The number of coefficients required to specify such a polynomial is `n + d choose n`, which in high dimensions is much less than `n^d` coefficients that could fill a cube of side length `n`. As a result, in my situation I have to store the coefficients rather compactly. This is at a price, because retrieving a coefficient for a given multi-index `alpha` requires knowing its location.

### The question

Is there a (straightforward) function mapping a `d`-dimensional multi-index `alpha` to a position in an array of length `(n + d) choose n`?

Comment: Let me know if you have any questions concerning my answer.

Comment: It makes sense; the question for me is now whether I can use that compile-time info and ordering to make optimized code using some template magicks, or whether I actually should simply write a code generator for specific cases I run into. I guess that would require a separate question.

Comment: If you precompute the binomials, the index calculation will be very fast (taking `O(d)` time). You'll need `O(d²)` space to store the binomials, effectively storing a pascal triangle in memory. If `d` is not known at compile time you can always calculate the triangle on the fly (`O(d²)` time).

Comment: One can always use templates to compute the triangle; in fact, I have such code ready, so all that is stopping me is the need to write meaningful unit tests. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Ordering combinations

A well-known way to order combinations can be found on [this wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorial_number_system). Very briefly you order the combinations lexically so you can easily count the number of *lower* combinations. An explanation can be found in the sections **Ordering combinations** and **Place of a combination in the ordering**.

Precomputing the binomial coefficients will speed up the index calculation.

#### Associating monomials with combinations

If we can now associate each monomial with a combination we can effectively order them with the method above. Since each coefficient corresponds with such a monomial this would provide the answer you're looking for. Luckily if

```
alpha = (a[1], a[2], ..., a[d])
```

then the combination you're looking for is

```
combination = (a[1] + 0, a[1] + a[2] + 1, ..., a[1] + a[2] + ... + a[d] + d - 1)
```

The index can then readily be calculated with the formula from the wikipedia page.

Answer (score 1):

A better, more object oriented solution, would be to create Monomial and Polynomial classes.  The Polynomial class would encapsulate a collection of Monomials.  That way you can easily model a pathological case like

```
y(x) = 1.0 + x^50
```

using just two terms rather than 51.

Another solution would be a map/dictionary where the key was the exponent and the value is the coefficient.  That would only require two entries for my pathological case.  You're in business if you have a C/C++ hash map.

Personally, I don't think doing it the naive way with arrays is so terrible, even with a polynomial containing 1000 terms.  RAM is cheap; that array won't make or break you.

Comment: This would work well for polynomials in one variable.  But as the number of variables grows, OP is looking for a way to store the information.

Comment: Then it's a hash map where the key is the exponent and the value is a list of coefficients, one per variable.

Comment: I am indeed using C++ but I fear that a hash map is like using ABC weapons to kill a house fly. Also, your pathological case never happens.

RAM is an issue, as are cache misses, because there are going to be tons of polynomials used at the same time. Also, the fraction of wasted array entries grows very, very quickly with dimension.

Comment: The exponent is the complicated part, not the coefficients.  The naive way would take (n+1)^d terms, which can easily overwhelm your RAM.  But if the hash key is the list of d exponents, then it has at most (n+d) choose n keys, and everything should be pretty simple (why not use a bazooka on a house fly?).

Comment: @Teepeemm: yes, the problem is that most of those `(n+1)^d` coefficients are pointless. Using a bazooka on a house fly is really cool from time to time (dumping liquid nitrogen is funny, too), but collateral damage gets boring after a while. Seriously, though, hash map is a run-time thing while I am hoping for something that could perhaps be generated at compile-time.. there, hash map would slow down the code a lot.